# Where is the right place to ask descriptive questions on programming?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where do I ask this question on Stack Exchange?

Here's my question:

> I have learned nodes-express-MongoDB and building [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) APIs using
> them. Now I want to develop a mobile app for a website that is built
> in PHP and MySQL. I don't know PHP.  For the mobile app I need a REST
> API for that website.
>
> Can I build it using nodes-express? If so, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nowhere.

You're coming to us with a question which is too broad, in that you wish to build something using a technology you have no experience in.

You're not looking for *help*; you're looking for us to *teach* you, which is not what technical Stack Exchange sites are equipped to do.

I would actually not encourage you to post this question anywhere, and instead get more familiar with PHP and MySQL.  Once you have enough experience in those arenas to ask more pointed questions about your REST endpoints, we might be able to help you out then.